# Can't set Nav Controller when testing Fragment with Compose

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-jetpack-compose, android-testing

I'm trying to test a fragment that uses compose.

I'm having issues with setting my nav controller for the test.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    navController = findNavController()
    return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
        setContent {
            SampleScreen(
                onNavigationClick = {
                    navController.popBackStack()
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

@Test
fun testFragment() {
    val navController = TestNavHostController(
        ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
    )
    val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer{
        TestFragment().also { fragment ->
            fragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observeForever { viewLifecycleOwner ->
                if (viewLifecycleOwner != null) {
                    navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
                    Navigation.setViewNavController(
                        fragment.requireView(),
                        navController
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I need my `nav controller` in `onCreateView` so that it can be passed down to the composables. However, for tests it seems you can only set a `nav controller` at the earliest on `onViewCreated` because `Navigation.setViewNavController()` requires a view to work.

So I think I need to somehow have `findNavController()` in `onViewCreated()`. But I also need it in `onCreateView()` to pass it to my composables.

Am I structuring the fragment wrong here? How can I test this fragment and set the nav controller?

EDIT: Trying to move `setContent` to `onViewCreated`. This gets the screen to be blank.

```
override fun onViewCreated(
    view: View,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    navController = findNavController()
    ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
        setContent {
            SampleScreen(
                onNavigationClick = {
                    navController.popBackStack()
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just move your call to `setContent` to `onViewCreated()`?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample? I've edited my post to reflect what I've tried to do and it doesn't work. What needs to be in `onCreateView` and `onViewCreated`?

Answer (score 0):

You can move your `setContent` to `onViewCreated()` so that your call to `findNavController()` retrieves the `NavController` set via `setViewNavController`:

```
override fun onViewCreated(
    view: View,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    navController = findNavController()
    // The view passed to onViewCreated() is the one you
    // return from onCreateView() so we can safety cast it
    // to ComposeView
    (view as ComposeView).apply {
        setViewCompositionStrategy(DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
        setContent {
            SampleScreen(
                onNavigationClick = {
                    navController.popBackStack()
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Note the addition of the call to `setViewCompositionStrategy` as per the [ComposeView in Fragments guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#compose-in-fragments).